# fastcgi_path_info causes wrong fastcgi_script_name resulting in an 404

Tags: php, forms, nginx, fastcgi

I am encountering an issue on Nginx where the form action containing the full URL-Path can not properly be parsed by PHP-FPM. The root seems to be the following directive: fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;

According to this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-and-implementing-fastcgi-proxying-in-nginx the first capturing group is for the $fastcgi_script_name, the second for the $fastcgi_path_info variable.

In my logs I find: /files/wordpress-live/analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 217.50.183.28, server: mikeg.de, request: "POST /analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics/ HTTP/2.0", host: "mikeg.de"

The logs reporting an invalid path "/files/wordpress-live/analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics/index.php". Does someone have an idea how to split the post request path properly so PHP-FPM can pass it properly?

Many thanks & kind regards
Mike

Comment: What value are your expecting for `$fastcgi_script_name`?

Comment: It should be the root folder without the web url for posts. In this particular case solely /files/wordpress-live/

Comment: Please expand your question with relevant configuration files, particularly the website's `server { ... }` block.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your support. here is the server config in question: [Pastebin config](http://pastebin.com/LxJUtfRE)

Comment: Is it possible that the directory `/files/wordpress-live/analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics` actually exists on your system?

Comment: This path exists and represents the vhost root directory: /files/wordpress-live/

This is the website URL: analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics

The website with the form in question is: mikeg.de/analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics

Comment: For some reason `nginx` is behaving as though `analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics` exists as a real directory under your vhost root.

Comment: Thought so, the split path's directive regex 1st matching group catches script path which in terms of the form action is the URL https://mikeg.de/analytics/sampling-luegt-google-analytics/

I really don't know what I am missing …

Comment: I had reproduced this misbehavior with the Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. In the root location block POST request were also defined causing those requests not to skip the cache thus resulting in this awkward behavior.